# ReactJs + Auth0-Lock: Access Custom fields in Universal login

Tags: reactjs, auth0, auth0-lock

I added additionalSignUpFields via Auth0-Lock for firstName, lastName and state to my Universal login.

```
const lock = new Auth0Lock(process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN, {
    auth: {
        redirectUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL,
        responseType: 'token',
    },
    closable: false,
    initialScreen: 'signUp',
    additionalSignUpFields: [
        {
            name: "firstName",
            placeholder: "Enter your first name"
        },
        {
            name: "lastName",
            placeholder: "Enter your last name"
        },
        {
            name: "state",
            type: "select",
            placeholder: "choose your region",
            options: [
                {value: "new_york", label: "New York"},
                {value: "new_jersey", label: "New Jersey"},
                {value: "washington", label: "Washington"},
                {value: "ohio", label: "Ohio"},
                {value: "iowa", label: "Iowa"},
            ],
            prefill: "ohio",
        }
    ]
});
```

My question is how do I access the custom fields?
I tried accessing the "claims" and "user" objects but I do not see the custom fields

```
const { user, getIdTokenClaims } = useAuth0();
let claims = getIdTokenClaims(); 

console.log(user);
console.log(claims);
```

Here's the output that I get...
[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction - how do I access the custom fields?